# application based on create-react-app does not work with redux-saga

Tags: create-react-app, redux-saga

I'm working on application which is based on create-react-app. I need to add redux-saga to the stack and it doesn't work.

I added sagaMiddleware in store:

```
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';
import sagas from './sagas';

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
const middlewares = [sagaMiddleware, createDebounce(), thunk, exponentialRetry, routerMiddleware(history)];
const store = createStore(reducer, composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(...middlewares)));
store.runSaga = sagaMiddleware.run(sagas);
```

I have an action, which is dispatched on `componentDidMount`. I can see it was dispatched in reducer, which listens on this action also.

I have a saga file:

```
import { takeLatest } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import { FETCH_TASK } from './types';

export function* fetchTaskById(id) {
  console.log('id', id);
}

export default function*() {
  yield takeLatest(FETCH_TASK, fetchTaskById);
}
```

I have a file which gathers all sagas from different files in one rootSaga and is imported in store:

```
import { fork, all } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import TaskFormSaga from './containers/task-form/sagas';

const sagas = [...TaskFormSaga];

export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield all(sagas.map(fork));
}
```

Everything looks fine from code perspective but `fetchTaskById` saga is never called. Also if I add console.log in saga's export default function it is never written on the console.

I would appreciate a hint what could be wrong.

Comment: `Also if I add console.log in saga's export default function it is never written on the console.` In export default of the rootsaga or the task saga?

Comment: @MartinKadlec task saga

Comment: I'd check that TaskFormSaga is truly an array of sagas.